# Can one app be replaced by another app in same team Id in Itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have two app in appstore. Lets say App A and App B. They have different App Id, Bundle Id and SKU. App A is in sale in appstore with version 1.4. App B is not in sale. I want to replace App A by App B and with version 2.2 onwards. How to delete App A and replace by App B and let user who has App A to know download App B or they can get their app release automatically?

Comment: You can't replace one app with another; Just submit an update to App A with the new code and the new version but the same bundle ID

Comment: Is it possible to replace Bundle Id  of App A by App B ?

Comment: No, the bundle ID *is* the app - If you use a different Bundle ID then it is a different app and the user would have to download and install that app from the App Store.

Comment: If I ask user to download App B and then if I remove App A, would app A still be in user devices?

Comment: Yes.  People who have "purchased" (whether free or otherwise) App A will always be able to download it, even if you remove it from sale.

Comment: Thank you very much :) . If there is any ways to remove app from user, it would be great because both App  has same icon and user would be confused.

Comment: That is why it would be better to simply release the "new" app as an update to the "old" app.  That way people who have the old app simply get the new app as an update (Many people will have automatic update on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If you want to replace/update an existing app, you will always need to use the exact same `bundle id` and a higher version code.

Answer (score 0):

The way to replace app A with app B is to copy all the code from app B to app A, rebuild A, and submit A with it's original bundle ID, but new code and a higher version number.  If B isn't for sale, Apple might not reject A as being a duplicate app.  If they do, you might have to remove or change B first.